# $http call twice: OPTION and then GET in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call an HTTP GET via : 
this.$http.get(this.baseURL,  { headers: { 'apikey': 'abc' } })
But it doesn't run as I expect. When I debug on chrome it shows Request Method: OPTIONS and the Headers do not have apikey. What happened?

**Update:**
Actually, the request is called twice, first is OPTION and then GET. As I understand, it caused by "preflight": https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server

"Any request that does not meet the criteria above is a not-so-simple request, and requires a little extra communication between the browser and the server (called a preflight request), which we’ll get into below."

Comment: Change your question tag to "Angular". Because AngularJs and Angular are totally different and TypeScript is used in Angular.

Comment: I know that bro, actually my project is written on AngularJS and used TypeScript Definition for using TypeScript. But it is not Angular

Comment: So based on your update, you now know what is happening?  Do you still have some unanswered question here?

Comment: Yeah, I know what is happening here.